# what is the use of route 53 in aws when ISPs can also route traffic into our instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know route 53 can route dns traffic into our instances . but  why specially need to use route 53 when ISPs  can also provide same routing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to use route 53, especially if you are just, for example, routing http/https traffic to your web application - any dns provider will work just fine.

I have about 1/2 my domains with AWS, and 1/2 still outside - some of the aws specific features are easier if the domain is within AWS, but most of the time it really doesn't matter much at all - but more and more I am moving them into AWS just to keep the billing simpler (one bill).

Answer (score 0):

If your instances are inside AWS, Route 53 has better options in terms of ways of routing. For instance, you can put an ELB in front of your instance(s) then tell Route 53 to use an ALIAS record type to route traffic to that ELB. This allows you to move your instances into a private subnet.

The benefits of this approach is that your instances are no longer "out in the open" on the internet with a public IP. And depending on how you configured your public IP if it is not an Elastic IP, you will lose it if you ever stop/start your instance.

The "best practice" is to put all your instances in a private subnet, setup a NAT gateway so they can access the internet, then put ELBs in front of the instances (with an SSL certificate so it can terminate SSL), and finally, setup Route 53 to forward requests over the ALIAS record type. If you start/stop the instance, or if it dies and you replace it, there is no reconfiguration.